# Separating into multiple tables or put them all in one?

Tags: database-design

For self-learning purpose, I'm trying to create a simple web application that creates a TODO list where each list gets a unique URL. I currently use the following database design. The `onlinelist.list` table stores URL and password of each list. The `onlinelist.item` stores items stored in each list.

```
onlinelist.list                   onlinelist.item
+----+-----+-------------+        +----+---------+-----+
| ID | URL |  Password   |        | ID | Content | URL |
+----+-----+-------------+        +----+---------+-----+
|  1 | abc | rfk49gh34   |        |  1 | apple   | abc |
|  2 | pqr | 12345       |        |  2 | banana  | xyz |
|  3 | xyz | password123 |        |  3 | milk    | pqr |
+----+-----+-------------+        |  4 | beef    | abc |
                                  |  5 | egg     | abc |
                                  |  6 | pasta   | xyz |
                                  |  7 | lemon   | pqr |
                                  |  8 | carrot  | xyz |
                                  +----+---------+-----+
```

It makes me worry to see some URLs repeated in `onlinelist.item` table. To get all list items for the list stored at "abc", it would need to go through all elements of the table and find those where URL equals "abc". (I'm assuming this is how the SELECT statement works.) Deleting a list item would also need to perform this search.

Shouldn't it more efficient if I create a separate table for each list, i.e. `onlinelist.abc`, `onlinelist.pqr`, `onlinelist.xyZ`, so that the search does not need to look at irrelevant entries? But then, I think that it doesn't really make sense to have tables called `onlinelist.abc` or `onlinelist.xyz`. Do I already have a good design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing objects you should look at their relations. From your example I see two objects:

TODO list with properties:

- Id
- Url
- Password

TODO item with properties:

- Id
- Content

The URL property of your item does not seem to be bound to the item, rather to the list where the item belongs.

If you look at this from the relations perspective, you can say that the TODO item "belongs" to a TODO list or rather a TODO list has in it a collection of TODO items.

For this you have 1:N mapping between list and item entities (1 list has N items, 1 item belongs to 1 list).

To record this relationship you could modify the TODO item table in this manner:

```
onlinelist.list                   onlinelist.item
+----+-----+-------------+        +----+---------+--------+
| ID | URL |  Password   |        | ID | Content | ListId |
+----+-----+-------------+        +----+---------+--------+
|  1 | abc | rfk49gh34   |        |  1 | apple   |   1    |
|  2 | pqr | 12345       |        |  2 | banana  |   3    |
|  3 | xyz | password123 |        |  3 | milk    |   2    |
+----+-----+-------------+        |  4 | beef    |   1    |
                                  |  5 | egg     |   1    |
                                  |  6 | pasta   |   3    |
                                  |  7 | lemon   |   2    |
                                  |  8 | carrot  |   3    |
                                  +----+---------+--------+
```

In case you want to share an item on multiple lists, you can no longer do this with only two tables, but you will have to create a mapping table.

In that case you would leave the ListId from the onlinelist.item table and create a new one

```
onlinelist.mapping         
+----+--------+----------+ 
| ID | ListId |  ItemId  | 
+----+--------+----------+ 
|  1 |    1   |     1    | 
|  2 |    1   |     2    | 
|  3 |    2   |     1    | (with more mapping going on)
+----+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just after seeing ListID instead of URL in onlinelist.item, everything became suddenly clear.